# Graph API notification when Stream has completed processing of Teams recorded meeting

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

We want to have a clean way to pick up a recorded Teams meeting after Stream has completed processing so that we can do trigger additional tasks.

We are currently working around this with notification API based on email subject but hoping there is a better way. Saw this post about Stream API being on the roadmap - any chance beta version can be previewed?

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-stream-forum/is-microsoft-stream-api-api-available-now-in-2019/m-p/1001402

Welcome suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft graph change notifications currently do not support Microsoft stream events today. More generally Microsoft stream does not have a public API. You should [upvote the idea supporting an API for Microsoft Stream in Microsoft graph](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37545334-create-an-api-for-ms-stream) to help prioritize the work and receive updates.